# Show notification as root to other users on KDE

Tags: linux, debian, notifications, kde-4

I need to show notification messages to different users as root on a Debian system running KDE with a bash or python script.
What I tried so far are:

```
export DISPLAY=:X (X symbolizes the remote host data)
export XAUTHORITY=~$USERNAME/.Xauthority
zenity --warning --title $TITLE --text " $TEXT
```

These commands do what I want, but just through terminal. When I try to use them in a Python script (using os.system() or subprocess.call()) or try to run through a shell script; it fails (Usually showing notification to the user that I logged in, not to the target user. Also sometimes leads to the errors:

```
Could not open X display 
No protocol specified 
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :X. 
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
```

But also, it rarely shows the notification to the correct user. Therefore I could not understand the way it behaves.)

I also read that zenity is not good for KDE, rather kdialog is preferred.

```
kdialog --title "some title" --passivepopup "some text" 5 & (number for the time-out)
```

Using the above command with gksu and su, there is no success again. I also tried with pynotify. I guess the problem is not about the way I create the notification message but showing to the user, more directly, connecting to the X Server or transfering user specific X Server settings.

I need help at this point; any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Though I still do not know what the exact problem is with the above approach, I finally found a solution working great for my case.

```
cat /home/remote-user/.Xauthority | xauth merge -              #merge the Xauth information of user
DISPLAY=:X kdialog --title 'some title' --sorry 'some_message' (X symbolizes the remote host data)
```